Method in Appdelegate applicationWillTerminate not being called using SwiftUI iOS
I have an app which is setting up a VPN connection via Wireguard framework. App is using AppDelegate Lifecycle even if in SwiftUI. I'm using a real device.
I need to close my VPN connection started via Wireguard when app is manually closed by the user (not when in background, in that case I need connection alive), if user swipes the apps in order to close it, I'd expect the app to call applicationWillTerminate and call turnOffTunnel() before the app terminates. How to achieve this?
I do not want the vpn connection to be alive if app is closed. I can see that the VPN is still running if I check the VPN setting of iOS. On andoird a colleague of mine can do it, is it possible in iOS?
I tried:

Notification Center
semaphores
observing when the ContentView disappears (is the main View)
and set Application can be killed immediately when user is shutting down or logging out to NO

with this one, applicationWillTerminate when user closes the app via swipe, it is called, but not always. Still, my method is never called.
my app currently is NOT supporting background activity, but maybe in the future it will, I read this could somehow interfere, but info I found are a bit old
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import NetworkExtension

@main
struct testWireGuardInstructions01SwiftUIApp: App {
    
    //used to replicate old UIKit appDelegate 1/2
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(MyManager.shared)

        }
    }
}


//MARK: - section used to replicate UIKit app delegate behaviour

//used to replicate old UIKit appdelegate 2/2
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let myManager = MyManager.shared
    var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0);
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Logger.info("applicationWillTerminate")
        myManager.turnOffTunnel()
    }
    
}





//MARK: - ContentView

import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var myManager: MyManager
    
    @State private var isShowingWebView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Text(myManager.isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(myManager.isConnected ? .green : .red)
            
            //Simulate obtaining result of a QR code
            Button("Obtain Data from QR") {
                myManager.getConfigurationInfoFromQR()
            }
            
            Button("Start") {
                print("Start")
                myManager.turnOnTunnel { isSuccess in
                    if isSuccess {
                        NSLog("Starting tunnel succeeded")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button("Stop") {
                print("Stop")
                myManager.turnOffTunnel()
            }
            
            Button("Verify") {
                print("Verify")
                myManager.logConnecitonStatusEX()
            }
            
            Button("Logout") {
                myManager.removeTunnel { isSuccess in
                    NSLog("removeTunnel exitus: \(isSuccess)")
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) {}
}



//MARK: - MY MANAGER Class


import Foundation
import NetworkExtension
import Security
import LocalAuthentication



class MyManager: ObservableObject {
    ///Remeber to set providerBundleIdentifier properly in this class
    
    
    static let shared = MyManager() //here since I am using it in AppDelegate UIKit code
    var tunnelManager: NETunnelProviderManager?
    
    var wgQuickConfig: String?
    
    
    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    
    private init() {}
    
    // Assumptions:
    //   - We just need one tunnel in iOS Settings / macOS Preferences for the app.
    //     We can reuse that with different configs if required.
    //   - The tunnel shall not be started from iOS Settings / macOS Preferences.
    //     It has to be started using the container app only.
    //   - The tunnel need not be configured to start automatically under
    //     certain conditions using on-demand
    
    func turnOnTunnel(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        // Check if the tunnel is already connected, avoid multiple connections
        if isConnected {
            NSLog("Tunnel is already connected")
            completionHandler(true)
            return
        }
        guard let data = readFromKeychain(service: "com.example.myapp", account: "wgQuickConfig"),
              let wgQuickConfig = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            fatalError("No wgQuickConfig found in Keychain")
        }
        
        self.wgQuickConfig = wgQuickConfig
        
        // We use loadAllFromPreferences to see if this app has already added a tunnel
        // to iOS Settings or (macOS Preferences)
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { tunnelManagersInSettings, error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("Error (loadAllFromPreferences): \(error)")
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }
            
            // If the app has already added a tunnel to Settings, we are going to modify that.
            // If not, we create a new instance and save that to Settings.
            // We will always have either 0 or 1 tunnel only in Settings for this app.
            let preExistingTunnelManager = tunnelManagersInSettings?.first
            self.tunnelManager = preExistingTunnelManager ?? NETunnelProviderManager()
            
            // Configure the custom VPN protocol
            let protocolConfiguration = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
            
            // Set the tunnel extension's bundle id
            protocolConfiguration.providerBundleIdentifier = "yourtunnel.tunnelsxtension"
            
            // Set the server address as a non-nil string.
            // It would be good to provide the server's domain name or IP address.
            protocolConfiguration.serverAddress = "yourIP"
            
            
            //added by me
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            guard let wgQuickConfig = self.wgQuickConfig else {
                fatalError("no wgQuickConfig")
            }
            
            protocolConfiguration.providerConfiguration = [
                "wgQuickConfig": wgQuickConfig
            ]
            
            guard let tunnelManager = self.tunnelManager else {
                fatalError("no tunnel manager")
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            tunnelManager.protocolConfiguration = protocolConfiguration
            tunnelManager.isEnabled = true
            
            // Save the tunnel to preferences.
            // This would modify the existing tunnel, or create a new one.
            tunnelManager.saveToPreferences { error in
                if let error = error {
                    NSLog("Error (saveToPreferences): \(error)")
                    completionHandler(false)
                    return
                }
                // Load it back so we have a valid usable instance.
                tunnelManager.loadFromPreferences { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        NSLog("Error (loadFromPreferences): \(error)")
                        completionHandler(false)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // At this point, the tunnel is configured.
                    // Attempt to start the tunnel
                    do {
                        NSLog("Starting the tunnel")
                        guard let session = tunnelManager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession else {
                            fatalError("tunnelManager.connection is invalid")
                        }
                        try session.startTunnel()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.isConnected = true
                        }
                    } catch {
                        NSLog("Error (startTunnel): \(error)")
                        completionHandler(false)
                    }
                    completionHandler(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    ///Simply cuts off the vpn connection
    func turnOffTunnel() {
        
        
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { tunnelManagersInSettings, error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("Error (loadAllFromPreferences): \(error)")
                return
            }
            if let tunnelManager = tunnelManagersInSettings?.first {
                guard let session = tunnelManager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession else {
                    fatalError("tunnelManager.connection is invalid")
                }
                switch session.status {
                case .connected, .connecting, .reasserting:
                    NSLog("Stopping the tunnel")
                    session.stopTunnel()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isConnected = false
                    }
                    self.logConnecitonStatusEX()
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //remove from device preferences settigns
    //remove from keychain
    func removeTunnel(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { tunnelManagersInSettings, error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("Error (loadAllFromPreferences): \(error)")
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }
            
            guard let tunnelManager = tunnelManagersInSettings?.first else {
                NSLog("No tunnelManager found to remove")
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }
            
            tunnelManager.removeFromPreferences { error in
                if let error = error {
                    NSLog("Error (removeFromPreferences): \(error)")
                    completionHandler(false)
                    return
                }
                
                _ = self.deleteFromKeychain(service: "com.example.myapp", account: "wgQuickConfig")
                
                NSLog("Tunnel configuration removed successfully")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isConnected = false
                }
                self.logConnecitonStatusEX()
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}


As a general rule, what you're trying to do is not possible. In what cases are you seeing applicationWillTerminate called? It is somewhat rare that this happens (and I don't know any cases when the app is in the foreground). Your current code is returning before the async operation completes, so I would not expect it to survive long enough to finish, even in those somewhat rare cases where this method is called at all. If you want to catch when the user backgrounds the app, this is more often possible; watch for resign active (also called for phone calls)

I would be surprised if iOS doesn't terminate the vpn connection anyway when your app is terminated.

Hi @RobNapier the case is this one: I, the user, I'm using the app,  I used some recognition to retrive the data from keychain, If missing I create a vpn configuration. Connection start and I do my browsing. If I put the app in background, it is ok for VPN connection to be still on. BUT if I (the user) kill the app, the VPN should be terminated. but it is not being killed, in VPN phone settings is still on. Since on Android my colleague is killing the connection when app is closed, I'm looking for the same result. I added the code I'm using to be a bit more clear.

hi @Paulw11 me too! it is not terminating it. It is still alive in VPN section of iPhone settings.

How do you "kill" the app as a user?

hi @soundflix, via swipe, as always.

For the sake of clarity you should not use the term "kill" for this. It is "closing the app" in Apple's user descriptions, and "terminating" from a programming perspective.

@soundflix thank you, you are right! I will update the question right now. the method inside info.plist  confused me

It is not possible to reliably run code when the user swipes-up. There is no mechanism for this, by design. It looks like you're using an NETunnelProviderManager, which creates a system-level VPN. What it sound like you mean to have is an NEAppProxyProvider which provides an app-level VPN. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/app_proxy_provider

@RobNapier I chekked, yes, I'm using  NETunnelProviderManager, I think my institution won't use MDM, which iI understand is a requirement for using NEAppProxyProvider. but in case I could, would it be possible to implement such a feature ?

The way you've described it, no. This isn't about MDM, it's about whether it's an app-level VPN or a system-level VPN. For a system-level VPN, your app running or not running is going to be irrelevant. The system (not just the user) is free to kill your app any time you're in the background, and that shouldn't be expected to kill the VPN. If your connection is only in the foreground, then it would necessarily apply only to that one app, so an app-level VPN is what you would want (they can also handle a group of related apps). My gut is that what you're trying is not possible, though.
